# python evaluate module FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

When I first use the evaluate module, I follow the blog to download it. First use `pip install evaluate`  and use`python -c "import evaluate;print(evaluate.load('accuracy').compute(references=[1], predictions=[1]))"` to check it.
But it got an error like the one as follows

```
C:\Users\DELL>python -c "import evaluate; print(evaluate.load('accuracy').compute(references=[1], predictions=[1]))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\evaluate\loading.py", line 748, in load
    evaluation_module = evaluation_module_factory(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\evaluate\loading.py", line 681, in evaluation_module_factory
    raise FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find a module script at C:\Users\DELL\accuracy\accuracy.py. Module 'accuracy' doesn't exist on the Hugging Face Hub either.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLnlf.png)
I checked it probably because I didn't download the package of mertics, I went to github and downloaded the mertics package of evaulate, and put it in the evaulate folder in the package but it still didn't work
Last I choose the Jupyter to test the code, however it give the error

````
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 import evaluate
----> 2 print(evaluate.load('accuracy').compute(references=[1], predictions=[1]))

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\evaluate\loading.py:748, in load(path, config_name, module_type, process_id, num_process, cache_dir, experiment_id, keep_in_memory, download_config, download_mode, revision, **init_kwargs)
    703 """Load a [`~evaluate.EvaluationModule`].
    704 
    705 Args:
   (...)
    745     ```
    746 """
    747 download_mode = DownloadMode(download_mode or DownloadMode.REUSE_DATASET_IF_EXISTS)
--> 748 evaluation_module = evaluation_module_factory(
    749     path, module_type=module_type, revision=revision, download_config=download_config, download_mode=download_mode
    750 )
    751 evaluation_cls = import_main_class(evaluation_module.module_path)
    752 evaluation_instance = evaluation_cls(
    753     config_name=config_name,
    754     process_id=process_id,
   (...)
    760     **init_kwargs,
    761 )

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\evaluate\loading.py:681, in evaluation_module_factory(path, module_type, revision, download_config, download_mode, force_local_path, dynamic_modules_path, **download_kwargs)
    679         if not isinstance(e1, (ConnectionError, FileNotFoundError)):
    680             raise e1 from None
--> 681         raise FileNotFoundError(
    682             f"Couldn't find a module script at {relative_to_absolute_path(combined_path)}. "
    683             f"Module '{path}' doesn't exist on the Hugging Face Hub either."
    684         ) from None
    685 else:
    686     raise FileNotFoundError(f"Couldn't find a module script at {relative_to_absolute_path(combined_path)}.")

FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find a module script at C:\Users\DELL\accuracy\accuracy.py. Module 'accuracy' doesn't exist on the Hugging Face Hub either.
````